# c# - String Matching

Tags: c#, regex

i'm using a code to search number of strings and match them with one string.

my code:

```
foreach (string needle in list)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(haystack,needle))
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

is there any way to speedup the matching process?

Comment: Do you have to now if a specific needle is found, or is it ok that at least one needle is inside the haystack?

Comment: Examples, numbers, sizes, required performance?

Comment: -1:  Requesting better performing code with no baseline or examples is wasted time waiting to happen.

Comment: You do not even provide the regular expression.  How on earth can we help you?

Comment: thanks for help . i heard about strings multi-maching algorithm to speedup the matching time but i don't have an ideea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regular expressions are reasonable then most likely your current approach is OK. You may want to consider using compiled regular expressions instead of static IsMatch with strings.

If you need more speed - consider better algorithms (i.e. start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm ), you may be able to construct faster search for all patterns combined than individual ones.

Note that as with any performance problem there is no replacement for measurements - try and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to go through the whole list so that would imply an O(n) complexity at least.  One possible way to speed up the process would be to first sort your list but that will only increase your algorithm complexity to O(n Log n).